# Leave-one-out cross-validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to evaluate a multivariable dataset by leave-one-out cross-validation and then remove those samples not predictive of the original dataset (Benjamini-corrected, `FDR > 10%`).

Using the [docs on cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), I've found the leave-one-out iterator. However, when trying to get the score for the nth fold, an exception is raised saying that more than one sample is needed. Why does `.predict()` work while `.score()` doesn't? How can I get the score for a single sample? Do I need to use another approach?

**Unsuccessful code:**

```
from sklearn import ensemble, cross_validation, datasets

dataset = datasets.load_linnerud()
x, y = dataset.data, dataset.target
clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500)

loo = cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(x.shape[0])
for train_i, test_i in loo:
    score = clf.fit(x[train_i], y[train_i]).score(x[test_i], y[test_i])
    print('Sample %d score: %f' % (test_i[0], score))
```

**Resulting exception:**

```
ValueError: r2_score can only be computed given more than one sample.
```

**[EDIT, to clarify]:**

I am not asking why this doesn't work, but for a different approach that does. After fitting/training my model, how do I test how good a single sample fits the trained model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(x.shape[0])` is creating as many folds as the number of rows. This results in each validation run getting only one instance.

Now, to draw a "line" you need two points, whereas with your one instance, you only have one point. That's what your error message says, that it needs more than one instance (or sample) to draw the "line" that will be used to calculate the r^2 value.

Generally, in the ML world, people report 10-fold or 5-fold cross validation result. So I would recommend setting the `n` to 10 or 5, accordingly.

Edit: After a quick discussion with @banana, we realized that the question was not understood correctly initially. Since it is not possible to get the R2 score for a single data point, an alternative is to calculate the distance between the actual and predicted points. This can be done using
`numpy.linalg.norm(clf.predict(x[test_i])[0] - y[test_i])`

Comment: Although that is true, it does not answer my question. "I am trying to evaluate a multivariable dataset by leave-one-out cross-validation and then remove those samples not predictive of the original dataset. How can I get the score for a single sample?" Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: Okay, your question just changed. The answer explains why you need two data points to get a score, which is based on approximating a line (or curve) and then finding the distance of the actual data point from that line/curve. You need two points to generate a line. Predict, on the other hand, is along a single dimension, either you are correct, or your are incorrect. That's why it needs only one data point.

Comment: This might help to explain r2 values - http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_diagnostics_tab_7_2.htm

Comment: I know why it isn't working. I'm asking for a different approach (to achieve want I want) that does work. After fitting/training my dataset, how do I test how good one sample/point is against the trained model?

Comment: You could get predict the values, and then get the distance between the actual and predicted. `numpy.linalg.norm(clf.predict(x[test_i])[0] - y[test_i])`

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea. Can I ask you more about it [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57773/discussion-between-shashank-agarwal-and-banana)?